# Delphi records: can we do aggregate assignment?

Tags: c, delphi, records

Is there a way to perform aggregate assignment for Delphi records like we can in C and C++?
i.e. is there an equivalent syntax for the following:

```
struct silly { int x; int y; };
// ...
silly s = { 4, 5 };
```

for Delphi?

Comment: That C code is not aggregate assignment. That is initialization.

Comment: Technically correct for C++, where that would trigger a copy constructor.

Comment: This is tagged C, and that is initialization. But if it really is C, then it should be `struct silly s = ...`.

Comment: I mentioned C and C++. With C++ there's a noticable difference between initialization and assignment (copy constructors vs copy-assignment operators). Does C make any distinction between the two? Either way, the answer is delphi can't do that kind of aggregate assignment/initialization.

Comment: All I am saying is that the code in the Q is initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no exact equivalent. However, you can do some similar things.

For example, if

```
type
  TTestRecord = record
    A, B, C: integer;
    D, E, F: boolean;
  end;
```

and

```
var
  R1, R2: TTestRecord;
```

then you can do

```
R1 := R2;
```

Thus you can assign one record, by value, to another. But you cannot specify a 'record literal' in code. Something rather close to it, however, is pretty common: If you do

```
function TestRecord(A, B, C: integer; D, E, F: boolean): TTestRecord;
begin
  result.A := A;
  result.B := B;
  result.C := C;
  result.D := D;
  result.E := E;
  result.F := F;
end;
```

then you can write

```
R1 := TestRecord(1, 2, 3, true, false, true)
```

This is, for instance, how you handle `TRect` and `TPoint`. There are helper functions `Rect` and `Point` in `Classes.pas`.

**An aside:** In *constant* declarations, you can do somewhat more:

```
const
  R: TTestRecord = (A: 1; B: 2; C: 3; D: true; E: false; F: true);
```

Comment: Novelty record "constructors" (initializers) are also worth to mention.

Comment: @user539484: But you still need to write a procedure manually.

Comment: Sure thing, but this was a kind of borkadero attempt to bring a clarity to the struct initializers (unsuccessful, IMO). eg: instead of `Point(X, Y)` we can write `TPoint.Create(X, Y)`